# Finding Common Lisp Libraries

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, libraries, quicklisp

I'm using QuickLisp to load Common Lisp libraries. However, there are many libraries that all do similar things. For example, there are many libraries that all deal with parsing a CSV file.

Are there any resources you use to check which libraries meet your needs? How do you determine if a library is still being supported? Are there any heuristics short of visiting individual libraries's websites?

I'm aware of http://www.cliki.net/, which provides some recommendations.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://eudoxia.me/article/common-lisp-sotu-2015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two separate questions:

> Are there any resources you use to check which libraries meet your
>   needs?

I just use the library's official documentation, or quickdocs as mentioned earlier. I don't think there are any comparison tables between similar libraries. But you can always ask for help on #lisp on Freenode IRC network (since StackOverflow doesn't like questions like "What's the best CL library for parsing CSV?")

> How do you determine if a library is still being supported? Are there any heuristics short of visiting individual libraries's websites?

If a library is on Quicklisp then it is supported. Unsupported libraries usually drop out soon enough. Xach (Quicklisp's developer and maintainer) makes sure that there is no library in Quicklisp which can't be built on a supported CL implementation.

Answer (score 2):

you can try http://quickdocs.org/ 
it contains a number of references to widely used libraries from quicklisp, shows their last update time and some documentation. As for me, it was nice starting point to avoid the choice paralysis